# Merge two dataframes on variables of the same data type but get NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Here are two dataframes, df1 and df2.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uvacw/teaching-bdaca/main/12ec-course/week03/exercises/wozwaarde-clean.csv")
df1 = df1.melt(id_vars=['wijk', 'code', 'stadsdeel'],
                  var_name='year',
                  value_name='wozwaarde')
df1
```

```
    wijk    code    stadsdeel   year    wozwaarde
0   Burgwallen-Oude Zijde   A00 Centrum 2014    263417.0
1   Burgwallen-Nieuwe Zijde A01 Centrum 2014    267895.0
2   Grachtengordel-West A02 Centrum 2014    490251.0
3   Grachtengordel-Zuid A03 Centrum 2014    469946.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
486 Nellestein  T95 Zuidoost    2018    170441.0
487 Holendrecht/Reigersbos  T96 Zuidoost    2018    181189.0
488 Gein    T97 Zuidoost    2018    199542.0
489 Driemond    T98 Zuidoost    2018    267328.0
```

```
df2 = pd.read_excel("https://cms.onderzoek-en-statistiek.nl/uploads/2021_jaarboek_2112_28485510ff.xlsx",
                   skiprows=2,
                   skipfooter=2)
df2.drop([0,9], inplace=True)
df2['stadsdeel'] = df2['stadsdeel'].apply(lambda s: s.split()[-1])
df2
```

```
    stadsdeel   2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021
1   Centrum 86499.0 86422.0 86851.0 86862.0 87310.0 87083.0
2   Westpoort   200.0   192.0   198.0   177.0   106.0   145.0
3   West    143964.0    143842.0    144210.0    145908.0    147421.0    148030.0
4   Nieuw-West  149397.0    151677.0    155781.0    157964.0    160124.0    159522.0
5   Zuid    143258.0    144432.0    145548.0    145966.0    146291.0    145301.0
6   Oost    132421.0    135767.0    137454.0    140300.0    142049.0    141453.0
7   Noord   92917.0 94766.0 96275.0 97200.0 99238.0 100887.0
8   Zuidoost    86057.0 87854.0 87999.0 88610.0 89841.0 90076.0
```

Since df2 is a wide data, I want to melt it to a long data.

```
df2 = df2.melt(id_vars = 'stadsdeel',
               var_name = 'year',
               value_name = 'population')
df2
```

```
stadsdeel   year    population
0   Centrum 2016    86499.0
1   Westpoort   2016    200.0
2   West    2016    143964.0
3   Nieuw-West  2016    149397.0
4   Zuid    2016    143258.0
5   Oost    2016    132421.0
```

I also added a step to make sure variables that I wanted to merge on are of the same type.

```
df1['year'] = df1["year"].map(int)
df2['year'] = df2["year"].map(int)
df1['stadsdeel'] = df1['stadsdeel'].map(str)
df2['stadsdeel'] = df2['stadsdeel'].map(str)
```

Finally, I tried to merge, but it turns out NaNs.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on = ['stadsdeel', 'year'])
df.head(20)
```

```
wijk    code    stadsdeel   year    wozwaarde   population
0   Burgwallen-Oude Zijde   A00 Centrum 2014    263417.0    NaN
1   Burgwallen-Nieuwe Zijde A01 Centrum 2014    267895.0    NaN
2   Grachtengordel-West A02 Centrum 2014    490251.0    NaN
3   Grachtengordel-Zuid A03 Centrum 2014    469946.0    NaN
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
    wijk    code    stadsdeel   year    wozwaarde   population
0   Burgwallen-Oude Zijde   A00 Centrum 2018    263417.0    86851.0
1   Burgwallen-Nieuwe Zijde A01 Centrum 2018    267895.0    86851.0
2   Grachtengordel-West A02 Centrum 2018    490251.0    86851.0
3   Grachtengordel-Zuid A03 Centrum 2018    469946.0    86851.0
4   Nieuwmarkt/Lastage  A04 Centrum 2018    295239.0    86851.0
```

I've checked the variable names, variable type(also dtype), and removing white spaces, but they all don't work. I don't know what else can I do.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! A reproducible pandas problem. I'm impressed. Nicely asked!

You were *almost* there.
I wound up changing very little, after verifying the district spellings.

```
def woz_melt():
    df1, df2 = _get_dataframes()

    assert set(df1.stadsdeel) == set(df2.stadsdeel)  # Yup, the spellings match!

    print(common_years := set(df1.year) & set(df2.year))
    df1 = df1[df1.year.isin(common_years)]
    df2 = df2[df2.year.isin(common_years)]

    print(df1.merge(df2, how="left", on=["stadsdeel", "year"]))
```

output:

```
{2016, 2017, 2018}
                        wijk code stadsdeel  year  wozwaarde  population
0      Burgwallen-Oude Zijde  A00   Centrum  2016   289984.0     86499.0
1    Burgwallen-Nieuwe Zijde  A01   Centrum  2016   296762.0     86499.0
2        Grachtengordel-West  A02   Centrum  2016   560841.0     86499.0
3        Grachtengordel-Zuid  A03   Centrum  2016   531225.0     86499.0
4         Nieuwmarkt/Lastage  A04   Centrum  2016   340364.0     86499.0
..                       ...  ...       ...   ...        ...         ...
289     Bijlmer-Oost (E,G,K)  T94  Zuidoost  2018   182291.0     87999.0
290               Nellestein  T95  Zuidoost  2018   170441.0     87999.0
291   Holendrecht/Reigersbos  T96  Zuidoost  2018   181189.0     87999.0
292                     Gein  T97  Zuidoost  2018   199542.0     87999.0
293                 Driemond  T98  Zuidoost  2018   267328.0     87999.0

[294 rows x 6 columns]
```

When faced with an unfamiliar dataset,
I simplified it to focus on only the relevant years,
the ones that can help the `.merge()` since they
appear in both dataframes.

Doing a `.dropna()` on that result discards just five rows.
If that is OK, then one could ignore `common_years` entirely
and simply do a dropna on your original merge result.

The assessed property value figures are per-neighborhood,
but of course population figures are only at a district granularity.
So a `.groupby()` might be the next step.

Looks like a tidy dataset, now!